# An array of user id's that you want to display information of; how do you filter for those elsewhere in the code?

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, snapshot

Say you have a subset of users in an array via their uid. You want to display the information of these users in your application. So how do you use this array elsewhere in the code to only display for those uids.

There are 2 pages where I have to do this, and on one I managed to fix it with `if self.array1.contains(people.key)` However on the second page (I assume because it is structured differently), that does not work.

//Part 1: The array and current attempt

```
var array1 = [String]() ///this is at top of code before viewDidLoad
```

///In view did load

```
if let unwrappedName = name {
   self.array1.append(unwrappedName)
                    }
                    }

    print(self.array1, "ahah")
```

///Also in view did load, in a dataSnapshot, above the array definition

```
refArtists = Database.database().reference().child("people");
refArtists.observe(DataEventType.value,  with: {snapshot in
    for people in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
        if people.key != thisUsersUid {
            **if Calendar.current.isDateInToday(date) &&  countb >= 1 && self.array1.contains(people.key) {**
            }
            ...
                self.people.append(peopl)
                ...
                self.people.sort(by: { $0.TodayLikeCount ?? 0 > $1.TodayLikeCount ?? 0 })
            print("aaaaaaaa", self.people.map {$0.TodayLikeCount})
            
            self.table.reloadData()
```

///How is this page structured:

```
1)class ranking: UITableViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate{
2) All the definitions like var = this, let this = that etc
3)public override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
4)public override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell ///Return cell is made here
5)override func viewDidLoad(), super.viewDidLoad(), table.dataSource = self, table.delegate = self
6) **The refArtist.obeseve snapshot posted above**
7)**The defining of the array**
8)Other code
```

Answer (score 0):

For filtering an array and show it, you have to create another array and store the sorted results in that array, and use that array to reload the tableView. Also initially keep that array same as peopleArray by default. Then you can pass around this array to other pages as well.

```
var filteredArray = [String]() // declare at the top
```

Inside the viewDidLoad

```
filteredArray = self.people.sort(by: { $0.TodayLikeCount ?? 0 > $1.TodayLikeCount ?? 0 })
self.table.reloadData()
```

Hope you are clear.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense I think. To store the array that I have currently in filteredArray, do I just say filteredArray = array1? I am also getting Cannot assign value of type '()' to type '[String]' for the second part

Comment: or do you mean something like:                             let peopleArray1 = people.key
                            let filteredResults = peopleArray1.filter { person in

Comment: You can use filteredArray = array1, to initially assign default array.

Comment: Thanks. I did try that over the weekend. Got Cannot assign value of type '()' to type '[String]' error. The criteria that I am sorting by is independent of the array. So at the moment I am sorting via that criteria, and I need that to happen for only the uids in my array

Comment: What I still find peculiar is that && self.array1.contains(people.key) worked on the other page. There I also had a sort, but a different sort.